# Not davening the musaf of Rosh Chodesh on Shabbos Rosh Chodesh

Tags: shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf

If someone by mistake didn't say atah y'ztarteh (the special tefillah we say by musaf on Shabbos that is also rosh chodesh) and instead davened a regular musaf on shabbos rosh chdoesh, what's the din b'dieved?

I once heard that if someone davened a normal musaf on SHabbos Chol HaMoed Pesach they would be yotzee b'dieved since in musaf we say "musafim c'hilchasem" in a normal musaf of Shabbos it implies all musafim, even that of the yom tov. Perhaps so to here, even that of Rosh Chodesh.

Is this true? What's the din b'dieved in the original question? Who speaks about this? What other proofs could there be one way or another?

Answer (score 1):

*Aruch Hashulchan* 425:1 says that if even only the end of the *b'racha* was said as on every other week, one must repeat the *amida*. *Mishna B'rura* disagrees, but I suspect he'd agree to repeat the *amida* if no mention of *rosh chodesh* was made at all, especially because *AHS*'s argument against *MB*'s position is that the end of the *b'racha* is its main part.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Kaganoff actually went into detail on this in his commentary on Parshas Re'ei [This Shabbos Is Rosh Chodesh: What If I Goofed And Said Tikanta Shabbos By Mistake?](http://baltimorejewishlife.com/news/news-detail.php?SECTION_ID=45&ARTICLE_ID=78202)

I should note that this deals with one who realizes in the middle of shmoneh esrai that he has made a mistake. Rabbi Kaganoff does not speak about someone who has already begun Retzai (and Modim anachnu lach) or someone who has finished the entire Shemona Esrai before realizing his mistake. As always, since it is a machlokes, **CYLOR** to see what your rav says.

In any case, may you have the zechus to have this only be a theoretical question.

There is a machlokes between those who say that one goes back to Ata Yatzarta again and those who say that one adds the specific Rosh Chodesh sections to the Shabbos sections that were already said. Rabbi Kaganoff goes into detail on this. His opinion is that we do not go back as one is not supposed to repeat the parts that he actually said. However, this leads to a somewhat complicated method of "fixing" the shmonah esrai that he then explains in detail.

[This Shabbos Is Rosh Chodesh: What If I Goofed And Said Tikanta Shabbos By Mistake?](http://rabbikaganoff.com/?s=tikanta+shabbos)

> I once edited an article in which the author quoted several
>   anthologies, each of which ruled that someone who realizes he is
>   saying Tikanta Shabbos on Shabbos Rosh Chodesh should immediately stop
>   where he is, and go to the beginning of Atah Yatzarta, and recite the
>   entire bracha. However, I believe that this ruling is in error. I will
>   explain shortly why I believe that this answer is erroneous.  But
>   first…
>
> I attempted to trace the sources quoted in the article to see if
>   perhaps I was missing some logic or information that I would clarify
>   in the course of my research.
>
> What I did discover was that each source was simply quoting a
>   previous one, and that they all traced to one obscure 19th century
>   work, which did not explain at all the reason for the ruling.
>
> I will now explain why I believe this ruling is in error, and what
>   one should do. My major concern is that the approach that these works
>   advocate results in repeating many parts of the shemoneh esrei, and
>   that this repetition constitutes a forbidden interruption in the
>   tefillah. Furthermore, to the best of my knowledge, there is no
>   essential requirement to recite this middle bracha of the shemoneh
>   esrei precisely in order.
>
> Obviously, one should maintain the order as is, but there is ample
>   evidence from major halachic authorities that, in general, mistakenly
>   rearranging the order of a bracha is not calamitous (see, for example,
>   Rosh, Taanis 1:1; Shu”t Igros Moshe, Orach Chayim 4:18 and 4:70:14).
>   Thus, when left with the choice of rearranging the order of a bracha
>   to avoid repetition, or repeating parts of the bracha and ignoring
>   what was already said, one should follow the first approach.
>
> Subsequently, I realized that the position I have followed, is indeed
>   that of Rav Moshe Feinstein. However, it appears that, in general,
>   there are other halachic authorities who feel that the text of a
>   brocha should indeed be kept intact even when repetition will result
>   (see, for example, Mateh Efrayim 582:10; Mishnah Berurah 582:16; Biur
>   Halacha 127:2 s.v. Aval).
>
> Based on my opinion, it appears that someone who discovers that
>   he/she began reciting Tikanta Shabbos rather than Atah Yatzarta should
>   mention only those parts of the bracha that he/she has as yet not
>   recited, but not repeat any theme or part of the bracha that one has
>   already said. Although fulfilling this may be confusing to someone
>   unfamiliar with the bracha, this should provide us with a valid reason
>   to pay more attention to the details of this bracha and understand its
>   different parts.
>
> In order to explain how one does this correctly, brachos of Atah
>   Yatzarta and Tikanta Shabbos into their constituent parts, so that we
>   can identify which parts we should not repeat. We can divide these
>   brachos into the following seven sections.
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   1. The introduction – from the words Atah Yatzarta until and including the words shenishtalcha (some recite the text hashelucha)
>   bemikdashecha.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   1. The introduction – from the words Tikanta Shabbos until and including the word kara’ui.
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   2. The prayer for our return – beginning with the words Yehi Ratzon – until (and including) the word kehilchasam.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   2. The prayer for our return – beginning with the words Yehi Ratzon – until (and including) the word kehilchasam.
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   3. The sentence that introduces the mention of the pesukim of the Musaf – Ve’es Musafei Yom HaShabbos Hazeh veyom Rosh Hachodesh… until
>   (and including) the word ka’amur.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   3. The sentence that introduces the mention of the pesukim of the Musaf – Ve’es Musaf Yom HaShabbos Hazeh… until (and including) the
>   word ka’amur.
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   4. Mention of the pesukim of the korban Musaf of Shabbos.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   4. Mention of the pesukim of the korban Musaf of Shabbos.
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   5. Mention of the pasuk of the korban Musaf of Rosh Chodesh and the passage Uminchasam… until (and including) the word kehilchasam.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   5. No equivalent
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   6. The paragraph Yismechu Vemalchusecha that concludes with the words zeicher lemaasei vereishis.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   6. The paragraph Yismechu Vemalchusecha that concludes with the words zeicher lemaasei vereishis.
>
> Shabbos Rosh Chodesh
>   7. The closing of the bracha -- Elokeinu Veilokei Avoseinu.
>   Regular Shabbos
>   7. The closing of the bracha -- Elokeinu Veilokei Avoseinu.
>
> We should note that the closings of these middle brachos of Musaf
>   shemoneh esrei are very different. On Shabbos Rosh Chodesh we recite a
>   version that is almost identical to what we recite on a weekday Rosh
>   Chodesh, but we insert three passages to include Shabbos.
>
> Parts 2, 4 and 6 of the two brachos are identical, whether it is
>   Shabbos or Shabbos Rosh Chodesh. Therefore, one should not repeat
>   these sections if one has said them already.
>
> Part 1 on Shabbos Rosh Chodesh, Atah Yatzarta, is very different from
>   what we usually recite on a regular Shabbos. Therefore, someone still
>   in the middle of this bracha should recite this passage again.
>
> If someone missed part 5, mention of the pesukim of Rosh Chodesh, and
>   is still in the middle of this bracha, he/she should recite it and
>   introduce it with the section 3 above, which introduces the korbanos
>   of the Musaf. However, if he/she already recited the pesukim of
>   Shabbos korban Musaf (#4) above, he should omit the reference to
>   Shabbos in this piece and only mention Rosh Chodesh. In the latter
>   case, one should change the plural Musafei to a singular Musaf since
>   he/she now is only mentioning the Rosh Chodesh Musaf.
>
> Having explained the rules governing these halachos, I will now
>   present the conclusions in a hopefully clearer way, depending on when
>   you discover your mistake:
>
> A. If you were still reciting the beginning of Tikanta Shabbos, and
>   had not yet reached Yehi Ratzon: Return to Atah Yatzarta and recite it
>   in order without any changes.
>
> B. If you had already begun the Yehi Ratzon, but are before Ve’es
>   Musaf Yom HaShabbos Hazeh: Complete the Yehi Ratzon until Ve’es Musaf;
>   then recite Atah Yatzarta until the words Yehi Ratzon, then resume
>   from the words Ve’es Musafei Yom HaShabbos Hazeh Veyom Rosh Hachodesh
>   from the Shabbos Rosh Chodesh Musaf and continue through the rest of
>   the tefillah.
>
> C. If you had just begun Ve’es Musaf Yom HaShabbos Hazeh: Add the
>   words Ve’es Musaf Yom Rosh Hachodesh Hazeh, and then continue in the
>   Shabbos Rosh Chodesh Musaf until Yismechu Vemalchusecha. Immediately
>   prior to saying Yismechu Vemalchusecha insert the words from Atah
>   Yatzarta until the words shenishtalcha bemikdashecha. Then return to
>   Yismechu Vemalchusecha and recite the rest of the tefillah in order.
>
> D. If you are already in the middle of Ve’es Musaf Yom HaShabbos
>   Hazeh: Recite Uveyom Hashabbas… until Veniskah. Then insert the words
>   from Atah Yatzarta until the words shenishtalcha bemikdashecha. Then
>   return to the words Ve’es Musaf but say the following: Ve’es Musaf Yom
>   Rosh Hachodesh Hazeh until the word ka’amur. Then say Uverashei
>   Chadsheichem in the Shabbos Rosh Chodesh section and continue in
>   order.
>
> E. If you are in the middle of Yismechu Vemalchusecha, complete it
>   until Zeicher lemaasei vereishis, and then insert the words from Atah
>   Yatzarta until the words shenishtalcha bemikdashecha. Then return to
>   the words Ve’es Musaf but say the following: Ve’es Musaf Yom Rosh
>   Hachodesh Hazeh until the word ka’amur. Then say Uverashei
>   Chadsheichem in the Shabbos Rosh Chodesh section. Then go to Elokeinu
>   Veilokei Avoseinu (after Yismechu Vemalchusecha) and finish the end of
>   the bracha and the davening.
>
> F. If you are already in the middle of the closing part of the bracha
>   (Elokeinu Veilokei Avoseinu) complete the clause that you are saying,
>   and then insert the words from Atah Yatzarta until the words
>   shenishtalcha bemikdashecha. Then return to the words Ve’es Musaf but
>   say Ve’es Musaf Yom Rosh Hachodesh Hazeh until the word ka’amur. Then
>   say Uverashei Chadsheichem in the Shabbos Rosh Chodesh section. Then
>   return to chadeish aleinu beyom hashabbos hazeh es hachodesh hazeh and
>   finish the end of the bracha in the Shabbos Rosh Chodesh section.
>
> If you completed the entire bracha of Tikanta Shabbos, but mentioned
>   in the middle of the bracha some reference to the korban Musaf of Rosh
>   Chodesh, you have fulfilled the requirements of this prayer and you
>   should continue Retzei (see Mishnah Berurah 423:6). If you completed
>   the bracha of Tikanta Shabbos but did not yet begin Retzeih, you
>   should say “vena’aseh lefanecha korban Rosh Chodesh hazeh” – “and we
>   shall do before You this Rosh Chodesh offering” and then continue with
>   Retzei (ibid.).